# A Non-Flash, Ajax based JQuery File Uploader

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am looking for a Javascript file uploader scipt with the following criteria

- JQuery Compatible
- Does not use Flash(means no swfupload)
- Can handle large files(in Megabytes range)
- Does not have too many dependencies (optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) (from the guys who did TinyMCE). It's jQuery compatible, you don't have to use the Flash option, and it's worked pretty well for me in a couple of projects. It has a pretty solid API.

Comment: I am not so sure about this script. I tried running the custom upload example in their documentation page and it caused an error.

Comment: @arvinsim I've had good results from this. Not sure about the error on their documentation page? I'd suggest downloading running it locally and testing with your own code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AjaxFileUpload plugin https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://www.albanx.com/
or this http://www.albanx.com/?pid=5&subid=21 (this handle large files and support preview drag and drop anf limit connections). It's only html and javascript, no flash , no silverlight or other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted, this plugin has been released: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

It's got great documentation and I was able to implement a customized file upload interface using its API. However it also comes with its own interface, if you don't want to implement your own interface.

Answer (score -1):

may be you use that's called by phpFileUploader.

Comment: or you can use a jquery extension lib   jquery.form.js  , you try search this word 'maslup' will be find